# What does "stand to" mean in the context of semiotics?

Tags: meaning

What does "stand to" mean in the following quotation of Charles Peirce?:

'A Sign, or Representamen, is a First which stands in such a genuine triadic relation to a Second, called its Object, as to be capable of determining a Third, called its Interpretant, to assume the same triadic relation to its Object in which it stands itself to the same Object."

"Stand for" means "to represent, or symbolize"

To me, "stand to" in the above quotation has a military sense: "To take up positions for action", so the sign take up the position of its object as to be capable of determining its interpretant. It really makes sense?

Comment: It's not "stand to", but "stand in (a) relation to"; *stand* is just a more vigorous way of saying *be*.

Comment: Did you copy it correctly? It should be "stand**s** in such"

Comment: Stoney and Chasly, you both are correct. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is "to stand in [some] relation to X"

'A Sign, or Representamen, is a First which stands in [such a genuine triadic] relation to a Second, called its Object

Comment: Semantically, has the idiom "to stand in [some] relation to X" exactly the same meaning" of "to be in [some] relation with X"?

Comment: The word is "syntactically" not "semantically"